# Doc2vec most_similar method returns similarity score higher than 1

Tags: python, python-3.x, gensim, doc2vec

I have trained doc2vec model by following this tutorial for 500.000 documents.
https://github.com/abtpst/Doc2Vec/blob/master/trainDoc2Vec.py

However, when I try to find most_similar documents for a given document, the results have similarity higher than 1. As you can see in the code and the outputs, docvecs.similarity returns 0.246 and docvecs.most_similar return 9.996 for similarity between same two documents. You can see the code and the output below:

```
from gensim.models import doc2vec
def myhash(obj):
    return hash(obj) % (2 ** 32)    
model = doc2vec.Doc2Vec(hashfxn=myhash)
model = doc2vec.Doc2Vec.load("d2v.model")

tag1 = "012020171590"
tag2 = "0109201716181"

print(tag1 in model.docvecs.doctags)
print(tag2 in model.docvecs.doctags)

print(model.docvecs.similarity(tag1, tag2))
print(model.docvecs.most_similar(tag1))
```

Output:

> True
>
> True
>
> 0.24682570854972158
>
> [('0109201716181', 9.996172904968262), ('0120201611372', 9.853036880493164), ('010120166996', 9.613503456115723), ('012020173027', 8.97104263305664), ('01202017423', 8.886014938354492), ('01002009541', 8.783470153808594), ('00002004106', 8.682585716247559), ('0109201616963', 8.671405792236328), ('011020171931', 8.659266471862793), ('011020175199', 8.573907852172852)]

Library and System Versions:

Linux-4.9.0-6-amd64-x86_64-with-debian-9.4

Python 3.5.3 (default, Jan 19 2017, 14:11:04)

NumPy 1.14.3

SciPy 1.1.0

gensim 3.4.0

FAST_VERSION 1

Comment: What if you try `model.similarity(tag1, '0109201716181')? (That is, recalc the pairwise similarity for the reported most-similar tag.)

Comment: Separately: your lines messing with `hashfxn` are superfluous, since the `.load()` creates an all-new `model`. (Why are do you even think you need to change that?)

Comment: Actually I have recalculated pairwise similarity by print(model.docvecs.similarity(tag1, tag2)) (tag2 is '0109201716181') and it returns a valid value which is 0.24. model.similarity(tag1, '0109201716181') returns word similarity and I am interested in document similarity.

Comment: I think you are right about hashfxn thing, it is unnecessary. I followed same github repo to load doc2vec model which is https://github.com/abtpst/Doc2Vec/blob/master/testDoc2Vec.py and it uses same procedure to load doc2vec model.

I have also trained same model with default hash function and load model just like this: model = doc2vec.Doc2Vec.load("d2v.model"). It returned the same type of wrong results.

Comment: Hmm, the values in the `most_similar()` results *should* match the pairwise `model.docvecs.similarity()` for the same doc-pairs. How was the model initially trained, and was anything non-standard done to it? Can you make a tiny standalone example where the values differ?

Comment: If you are in fact modeling your code on any of the files in <https://github.com/abtpst/Doc2Vec/blob/master/trainDoc2Vec.py>, don't! It's very confused in its approach – in some ways outdated, in some ways just wrong in ways that could have never worked well. Don't call `init_sims()` in any model you're about to train. Don't call `train()` multiple times in a loop unless you're certain you know what you're doing. Etc. Pick another example as your template. Have you looked at the example `Doc2Vec` notebooks in the `gensim` `docs/notebooks` directory?

Comment: Thank you, I have trained with Doc2Vec notebooks in the gensim library and it worked very well.